# SUM Of time file is returning 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to sum up time field but it is returning 0.

If I use it like this:

```
   SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', ServiceEnd)) FROM Location L    
   INNER JOIN Interaction I
   ON L.Id = I.IdLocation     
   GROUP BY L.Id,L.Description
```

It works but as soon as I add where clause like this:

```
   SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', ServiceEnd)) FROM Location L    
   INNER JOIN Interaction I
   ON L.Id = I.IdLocation
   WHERE CAST(ServiceEnd as time) = CAST('00:00:00.000' as time(3))
   GROUP BY L.Id,L.Description
```

It returns 0 for each group. Please remember that some of the rows have 00:00:00.000 value

Without where clause count is like this:

**Location result set**

```
1091513
1939179
9562
0
2181382
164492
243632
1089518
```

Here is what I need this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,servicestart,CheckinTime) abondendedTime FROM Location L INNER JOIN
     Interaction I
     ON L.Id = I.IdLocation
WHERE ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY L.Id, L.Description,DATEDIFF(SECOND,servicestart,CheckinTime)
```

but it returns 600 rows instead of locations which are 8 as shown in above result set

Comment: Skip the JOIN and the GROUP BY, does the WHERE clause pass any rows?

Comment: What is datatype of ServiceEnd? Is it date datatype?

Comment: Its data type id time(3)

Comment: Why do you cast ServiceEnd to time in the where clause, if it already is time?

Comment: It is just for testing purposes. same result without cast

Answer (score 0):

What does this return?

```
SELECT L.Id, L.Description,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', ServiceEnd))
FROM Location L INNER JOIN
     Interaction I
     ON L.Id = I.IdLocation
GROUP BY L.Id, L.Description;
```

You have a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE CAST(ServiceEnd as time) = CAST('00:00:00.000' as time(3))
```

This only chosees `ServiceEnd` values that are 0.  Hence the sum is 0.

I might also suggest doing the calculation in seconds and then converting:

```
SELECT L.Id, L.Description,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', ServiceEnd)) / 60.0
FROM Location L INNER JOIN
     Interaction I
     ON L.Id = I.IdLocation
GROUP BY L.Id, L.Description;
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I created the query but it is returning wrong result. 600 records instead of 8.